# stop reloading ListView on Orientation Change in android

Tags: android, listview, android-orientation

I have a `ListView`, populated from a XML. Everything is working fine, but when i change my device's orientation(Portrait<-->Landscape) it reloads the `ListView`. I want to stop it. I have used  `onSaveInstanceState` and `onConfigurationChanged`. But it still reloads.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        alrowDataView = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("name");
    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,alrowDataView.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // lvrowDataView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_xml);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NOdata" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lvrowDataView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_xml);
    ParsingXml parsing = new ParsingXml();
```

After that general ListView operations...

and here is the code for `OnSavedInstanceState` and `onConfigurationChanged`.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("name", alrowDataView);
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, alrowDataView.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and these are the declarations

```
    private ListView lvrowDataView;
private ArrayList<RowData> alrowDataView;
RowDataAdapter adapterRowData;
```

I don't want to use `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Also,in `onSaveInstanceState` the ArrayListis null!!!

Comment: So, what is your reason for not wanting to use `configChanges` in your manifest?

Comment: well firstly it is not working,i have tried it!then it is just a demo!in the real one,there will be some other activity which i need to be refreshed.Thats why.I didn't knew that before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Is not working with latest android api 3.0+

You need to use like this

```
<activity
            android:name="YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 />
```